# Binding polymer paper-listbox to a php array from MySql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, polymer

I am new to polymer and I am trying to create a simple management web app for my company.
So I have a query from my database that returns a simple list of varchar (a list of names of customers), that I want to display in a paper-listbox element or iron-list element (the items will be clickable and show info about the person).

I have tried using straight php into the items property, but it doesn't work:

```
<iron-list items="<?php echo $jsonresult;?>" as="item">
```

I've tried using Polymer Expression but is not working.
I've tried using a script tag with some javascript code into it as a last chance, but nada.

All I see in the page is empty space.
I am using chrome on a fedora machine - VScode as IDE - xDebug to debug php.

How the hell do I do this?
the code is all in one script main-view.html:

```
<?php

//db data
$host = '192...... etc etc ';
$dbuser = 'myuser ';
$dbpass = 'mypass';
$dbname = 'mydatabase';

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if (!$conn)
{
    echo "Error: Unable to connect " . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging Error: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "Hurray" . PHP_EOL;
}

$sql = "SELECT username as user FROM mytable where condition";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "Query executed rows--> : " . $result->num_rows . " rows. " . PHP_EOL;
    $rows = array();

    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
}
```

?>

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

        <title>Title</title>

        <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
        <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
        <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
        <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">    

        <style is="custom-syle">

            .horizontal-section {
                padding: 0 !important; 
            }

            .avatar {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                overflow: hidden;
                background: #ccc;
            }

            paper-item {
                --paper-item: {
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }

            .sublist {
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
<body unresolved>
<dom-module id="main-view">
    <template>

    <div class="horizontal-section-container">
        <div>
            <h4 style="margin-left: 15px;">Customers Table</h4>
            <div class="horizontal-section">
                <paper-listbox id="list" items="[[arraySource]]">
                </paper-listbox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer ({
            is: 'main-view' 
        });
    </script>

    <script type="javascript">
        var arraySource = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
        document.getElementById('list').items = arraySource;
    </script>

</dom-module>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for the help, and sorry for the grammar --> english is not my first language.

Comment: check the ChromeDevTools if therei any error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok following some advice here, I've split this thing into two scripts, this is the result: 
It's working now.

list-view.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

    <!-- import the components to build up the list -->
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
</head>

<body>
    <dom-module id="list-view">
        <template>
            <div class="horizontal-section-container">
                <div>
                    <h4 style="margin-left: 15px; ">Customer Table</h4>
                    <div class="horizontal-section">
                        <paper-listbox id="list">
                            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[arraySource]]">
                                <paper-item on-tap="_itemTapped">[[item.user]]</paper-item>
                            </template>
                        </paper-listbox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

        <script>
            Polymer ({
                is: 'list-view',
                properties: {
                    arraySource: Array
                },

                _itemTapped: function (e)
                {
                    var item = e.model.item;
                    console.log(item);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>
</body>
```

main-view.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SITE</title>
    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./list-view.html">
</head>

<body>
    <dom-module id="main-view">
        <template>
            <div>
                <list-view id="list" array-source="<?php echo $jsonSource ?>" as="item"></list-view>
            </div>
        </template>

        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: 'main-view'
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract main-view component to a separate file and then import it:

```
<link rel="import" href="./main-view.html">
<body unresolved>
 <template is="dom-bind">
   <main-view></main-view>
 </template>
</body>
```

Otherwise it won't run.
Also, Try to use Polymer's data binding by defining your variable within Polymer object as such:

```
Polymer ({
    is: 'main-view',
    properties: {
       arraySource: {
         type: Array,
         value: function() { 
           return <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>; 
         }
       }
    }
});
```